# What is the work per length if you want to move two infinite parallel current-carrying wires?

Tags: electromagnetism, work, units

I'm having trouble trying to get the correct units of this problem.
The force per length is:
$$\frac{\vec{F}}{l}=\frac{-I_1I_2\mu _0}{2\pi r}\hat{r}$$
Let's say that the currents are 1A and the initial distance between them is 1 meter.
$$\frac{I_1I_2\mu _0}{2\pi}=\frac{A^2\times 4\pi \times 10^{-7}N/A^2}{2\pi}=2\times 10^{-7}N$$
Now, if we want to get the work per length I think (here is where I'm not sure) we can use the formula:
$$W=\int \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$$
In our case we want the work per legth and we know the force per length:
$$\frac{W}{l}=\int \frac{\vec{F}}{l}\cdot d\vec{r}$$
In our case:
$$\frac{W}{l}=\frac{-2\times 10^{-7}N}{l}\int _{1m}^{2m}\frac{dr}{r}$$
But the integral gives $\ln(2)$, so we don't have units of work. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What happened to the N/l factor outside the integral?

Comment: That is the factor associated with the currents and permeability and because they are constant they can go out of the integral, but to really have work per length the integral should give us something in units of length.

Comment: Be careful with the integral formula for work. What is the definition of the $\mathrm{d}\vec{r}$ here? What about the direction and the dot product?

Comment: $d\vec{r}$ is parallel to the direction of the force and it is a differential of the trajectory of the movement of the wire we are moving.

Comment: What about the $\hat{r}$ direction that you quoted in the force per unit length formula? It is a *radial* direction defined around the axis parallel to the wire. Is it in the same direction as the trajectory of the movement of the two wires?

Comment: $\hat{r}$ is parallel to the direction of the movement, but perpendicular to the two wires.

Comment: Here's another hint: if the current flows in the same direction in both wires, the *correct* behavior is that the two wires will *repel* each other. I think you're confusing the direction of the magnetic field generated by each current-carrying wire with the direction of the force.

Comment: @wyphan this is incorrect, parallel currents attract.

Comment: Whoops, @gs is right, it's been a while since I last taught E&M in an introductory physics class. Feel free to edit my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equation 5 doesn't follow from your previous equations. You've added an extra factor of 1/l by going from $rF/l = D$ (equation 2), where D is some constant with units of Newtons, to $rF/l = D/l$ in equation 5. If you get rid of the extra 1/l factor your dimensional analysis will check out.

---

**Edit with some additions.**

As a general piece of advice for all mathematical physics (and math in general): avoid numbers wherever possible until you're ready to calculate specific values.The 1/l error would likely not have been made if you had started by saying

*Given some constants $I_1$ and $I_2$*

*let $D = \frac {-I_1 I_2 \mu _0} {2 \pi}$*

*note that the units of D are $A*A*N/A^2 = N$*

---

Some things to note, that are useful to make explicit either in words or with a diagram:

By selecting some displacement vector $\vec r$ measuring the distance from one wire to the other, we have chosen the origin wire as a stationary reference frame and the source of the relevant fields. We have thus chosen the other wire as a moveable object with a magnetic charge which will be pushed or pulled by the relevant fields. We'll need this framing to be explicit so that we can use the right-hand rule to determine the direction of the force vector.

Also by assigning $\vec r$ we have chosen that the geometric origin (r=0) is along the axis of the first wire, and the $\hat r$ direction is positive for any forces, velocities, etc. Thus the negative sign in D indicates the direction of movement (towards the origin wire).

Digramming everything is a really good idea, and will help you identify what are the physical meanings of your implicit mathematical assumptions, and what are the physical meanings of your calculated results.

For instance, here you asked the question, "what is the work per length if *you* move the wire?" but the thing you have calculated is "what is the work done by the field on the free wire?" If we wanted to ask about *you* moving the wire, we would have to add a *you* to the system, applying a force equal and opposite the field's force. Diagram. Identify the physical meaning of every mathematical representation. Make all assumptions explicit. Make sure you are answering the question you are asking.